# What does this blockchain.info error mean?

Tags: bitcoind, blockchain.info, withdrawal

I added bitcoin payment to my website with bitcoin daemon, but one user is having an error with the blockchain.info API:

> Warning! this bitcoin address contains transactions which may be double spends. You should be extremely careful when trusting any transactions to or from this address.

https://blockchain.info/address/163cTKxPehxPi4nJ3oTHAso6eXWywfYr7N

Should I confirm this user's withdrawal, or should I block them? And what is significance of this error? If I use bitcoind to count confirmations, it's not dangerous to accept funds from such an address, right?? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a service which accepts deposits and withdrawals? Can you give an url? Do you know the address 1PN9vEwey7iikTHoKvrrUGJY7PtymhyNNV? Is it the deposit address of your service?

Comment: Why do you use both the bitcoind daemon and blockchain.info API?